# Как на типовой Ajax отправке почты сделать проверку reCapcha от гугла?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть типовая форма отправки данных.
**Как на Ajax сделать проверку нажатия галочки в гугл reCapcha? Чтобы можно было указать скрипт для ошибки и скрипт для успешной отправки** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Кроме вспомогательной пачки плагинов.

Типовой скрипт проверки отправки данных:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#writeAppointment").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php",
                data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                alert("Успешная отправка");
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так должно остановить отправку

```js
$("#writeAppointment").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      alert("Успешная отправка");
    });
  } else {
    alert('Неправильная капча')
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за участие!